# Proftpd does not initialize on startup

Tags: linux, debian, proftpd

I'm new here, and I'm also a new linux user, I'm using debian 12. I have the proftpd service configured and meeting my needs, but when I reboot the operating system, the service does not start automatically when the operating system loads.

i have to run "systemctl start or restart proftpd" command for the system to work.

I really need proftpd to work automatically when connecting to the server.

Answer (score 2):

If `systemctl status proftpd` does not say the service is currently **enabled**, you'll need `systemctl enable proftpd` to tell systemd the service should be started at boot time.

Conversely, if you want to stop a service from being started at boot, you can `systemctl disable <service name>`.

---

Debian 12's `proftpd` also includes provisions for *socket activation*: with a `proftpd.socket` unit, `systemd` is told to open a listening socket on behalf of `proftpd`, and the actual `proftpd` service would only be started by systemd when a first incoming FTP connection attempt arrives, and the incoming FTP connection(s) would be handed over to it. This would be similar to how the classic `inetd` and `xinetd` were used with certain services, to minimize system resource usage when idle. With `proftpd` specifically, this operation mode would require the configuration line:

```
ServerType inetd
```

in `/etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf`.

But since you said `systemctl start proftpd` makes the service work for you, it seems you have already configured proftpd for stand-alone operation, so the socket activation would not be relevant for you. In that case, you can (and should) disable the `proftpd.socket` unit, and have

```
ServerType standalone
```

in `proftpd`'s configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I checked and `ServerType standalone` was already configured in proftpd.conf. and the service was also enabled

`systemctl enable proftpd`

but, when I reboot the machine, the ftp stops working, until I run the `systemctl restart proftpd`

Comment: Does `journalctl -u proftpd.service` reveal any error messages that might explain it stopping?

Comment: the service does not stop, it is not starting at boot.

Comment: I thought maybe a script to start the systemctl restart command at boot, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

This problem exists also on Ubuntu 22.04, e.g. in Azure Cloud.
The reason is, that the daemon is started, as long proftpd isn't able to resolve its own `/etc/hostname` to IP. Later on, it's able to resolve.

As a workaround adding

```
[...]
127.0.0.1 your-servername-from-etc-hostname
[...]
```

to `/etc/hosts` should work.

But honestly, the deb package maintainers should fix this issue with a correct systemd configuration.